# Código não executa instrução corretamente em C++

Tags: c++

Eu tenho um código na main que funciona normalmente. Esse código diz que o usuário deverá informar os dados e  pede que o usuário digite o nome do funcionário e a instrução seguinte inicia o objeto i1. O objeto i1 chama seu construtor e o restante do código segue até o programa (na main) solicitar que o usuário digite o CPF do funcionário e a instrução seguinte inicia o objeto i1. O que eu não entendo é o que acontece quando eu altero o código da main. Quando eu insiro 4 linhas antes da linha que diz que o usuário deverá informar os dados, solicitando que o usuário informe quantos funcionários serão cadastrados, declaro uma variável quantidade, leio a variável quantidade informada pelo usuário e imprimo o valor da variável quantidade, o programa chega a imprimir que o usuário deverá informar os dados e pede que o usuário digite o nome do funcionário mas então o cursor já vai para a linha onde o usuário deve informar o CPF não permitindo que ele digite o nome do funcionário. Por que isso acontece?

```
//código da main que não está funcionando corretamente
int main()
{
    ofstream saidaArquivoCadastro( "cadastro.dat", ios::out );
    
    if ( !saidaArquivoCadastro ) // operador ! sobrecarregado
 {
 cerr << "Arquivo nao pode ser aberto" << endl;
 exit( 1 );
 }
 
    cout << "Informe a quantidade de funcionarios a serem cadastrados: ";
    int quantidade;
    cin >> quantidade;
    cout << quantidade;
    cout << "\nInforme os dados: \n\n";
    cout << "Nome do funcionario: ";
    info i1;
    cout << "\nCPF: ";
    info i2;

//código da main que está funcionando corretamente
int main()
{
    ofstream saidaArquivoCadastro( "cadastro.dat", ios::out );
    
    if ( !saidaArquivoCadastro ) // operador ! sobrecarregado
 {
 cerr << "Arquivo nao pode ser aberto" << endl;
 exit( 1 );
 }
 
    
    cout << "\nInforme os dados: \n\n";
    cout << "Nome do funcionario: ";
    info i1;
    cout << "\nCPF: ";
    info i2;

//descrição da classe info
#include <string>
using std::string;

#ifndef INFO_H
#define INFO_H

class info
{
    public:
        info (string = "");
        void setInfoDado (string);
        void setInfo ();
        void print () const;
    private:
        string infoDado;
};

#endif
  
  //descrição dos métodos info
  #include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

#include <string>
using std::string;
using std::getline;

#include "info.h"

info::info (string info)
{
    setInfoDado (info);
}

void info::setInfoDado (string info)
{
    infoDado = info;
    setInfo();
}

void info::setInfo ()
{
    string nome;
    getline (cin, nome);
    infoDado = nome;
}

void info::print () const
{
    cout << infoDado << "\n";
}
```

Percebi que esse problema acontece apenas quando eu coloco a instrução cin >> quantidade;. Quando eu não coloco essa instrução o cursor para em cout << "Nome do funcionario: "; para que eu possa digitar o nome do usuário (uma vez que ao instanciar o objeto i1  o método da classe info void info::setInfo () faz com que o programa espere o usuário digitar o nome). Quando eu coloco a instrução cin >> quantidade; algo faz com que esse método ou a instrução de atribuição no escopo desse método não seja executada. O interessante é que quando o objeto i2 é instanciado o código funciona normalmente (com ou sem a instrução cin >> quantidade; antes do objeto i1).

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 0):

> Eu tenho um código na main que funciona normalmente.

Talvez não funcione assim tão normalmente.

> Por que isso acontece?

A resposta curta é que você errou na declaração dos construtores de `info` e `familia` e invalidou o que talvez você achasse que era o construtor padrão para uma classe que só tem uma variável.

> Esse código diz que o usuário deverá informar os dados e pede que o
> usuário digite o nome do funcionário e a instrução seguinte inicia o
> objeto i1. O objeto i1 chama seu construtor e o restante do código
> segue até o programa (na main) solicitar que o usuário digite o CPF do
> funcionário e a instrução seguinte inicia o objeto i1

Isso que escreveu não faz muito sentido. Na prática

```
cout << "Nome do funcionario: ";
info i1;
cout << "\nCPF: ";
info i2;
```

você escreveu esses `cout` como prompts para orientar a leitura que acontece dentro do construtor, após você chamar 3 (!) funções. Não é uma idéia nada boa. Para alguém (incluindo você mesmo daqui um dia ou dois) entender o que o programa está fazendo teria que ter o código do construtor disponível a toda hora. Não faz sentido algum. A mensagem deveria estar junto da leitura ou ter sido passada como parâmetro.

A declaração da variável é que dispara a construção do mesmo. Só que escreveu errado. Provavelmente pretendia escrever isso

```
    familia() : Dado("") {};
```

Definindo o construtor padrão e colocando um `""` na única variável de sua classe. E teria funcionado.

Só que escreveu isso

```
class info
{
    public:
        info (string = "");
        void setInfoDado (string);
        void setInfo ();
        void print () const;
    private:
        string infoDado;
};
```

E acabou criando um construtor sem sentido que tem um parâmetro `string` que nada significa.

Podia usar algo simples como

```
class info
{
public:

    info() : Dado(""){};
    info(string prompt) { setDado(prompt); };
    void setDado(string);
    void print() const;

private:

    string Dado;
};
```

e `setDado()` receberia a mensagem a cada vez:

```
void info::setDado(string prompt)
{
    cout << prompt << ": ";
    getline(cin, Dado);
}
```

E usado simplesmente assim:

```
    info i1("Nome");
    info i2("CPF");
    i1.print();
    i2.print();
```